# 'The type or namespace name 'BookModel' could not be found ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am trying to display a Model based on an XML file in my View but I get the error as the title says. I have tried adding all references there are and it still does not work.

And also a side question, I am trying to make it able to search for any book (datatype) and the results should be displayed, shall I then give the LINQ statement to a  variable or what is the best solution?

Here's my code:

Model:

```
using System;

namespace Andre_Kordasti___Programmeringsuppgift.Models
{
    public class BookModel
    {
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<BookModel> @*error*@

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Sök</h2>

<input type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Sök" />
<br />
<a href="~/DataSource/books.xml">~/DataSource/books.xml</a>

@foreach (var book in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => book.Author)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => book.Title)
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Andre_Kordasti___Programmeringsuppgift.Models;

namespace Andre_Kordasti___Programmeringsuppgift.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            const string FILENAME = @"c:\users\andre\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Andre Kordasti - Programmeringsuppgift\Andre Kordasti - Programmeringsuppgift\DataSource\books.xml";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new
            {
                id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                author = (string)x.Element("author"),
                genre = (string)x.Element("genre"),
                price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
                date = (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"),
                description = (string)x.Element("description")
            }).ToList();

            var model = new BookModel();

            return View(results);
        }

        public ActionResult Fibonacci()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a couple of issues in your code.

Firstly, try to use the fully qualified name instead of partial name in your `View`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Andre_Kordasti___Programmeringsuppgift.Models.BookModel>
```

If you use partial name, you have to first use `using namespace_name` keyword before writing it.

```
@using Andre_Kordasti___Programmeringsuppgift.Models;
@model IEnumerable<BookModel>
```

Secondly, notice that the item you are passing from your `Controller` is anonymous, not exactly the `BookModel`:

```
var results = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new //anonymous here
{
    id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
    author = (string)x.Element("author"),
    genre = (string)x.Element("genre"),
    price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
    date = (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"),
    description = (string)x.Element("description")
}).ToList();
```

Change to:

```
var results = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new BookModel() //note the syntax here
{
    //Id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
    Author = (string)x.Element("author"),
    Genre = (string)x.Element("genre"),
    Price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
    PublishDate = (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"),
    Description = (string)x.Element("description")
    //use the same exact properties as your BookModel
}).ToList(); //ToList() may not be needed actually

var model = new BookModel(); //And this is...?
```

Comment: I wrote @model IEnumerable<Andre_Kordasti___Programmeringsuppgift.BookModel> as you said, but I get the same error!

Comment: @Cleon sorry, miss the `Models` there. I will update my answer. Your fully qualified name includes the `Models`, not just `Andre_Kordasti___Programmeringsuppgift`

Comment: I got this error when debugging! "System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`6[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Decimal,System.DateTime,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Andre_Kordasti___Programmeringsuppgift.Models.BookModel]'."

Comment: @Cleon this seems to come from your `Controller`? The `View` should be `OK` by now. But to pass the model correctly, the `Controller` passed items and the `Model` must be identical. This seems to be different error

Comment: @Cleon for instance, notice that your passed item is anonymous: `Select(x => new {`, the `new` keyword does not have strong-type. You should use `new BookModel`

Comment: var results = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new BookModel
            {
                Id = (int)x.Attribute("id"),
                Author = (string)x.Element("author"),
                Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
                Genre = (string)x.Element("genre"),
                Price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
                PublishDate = (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"),
                Description = (string)x.Element("description")
            }).ToList();

Comment: This seem to be correct now! Since its the same as the model properties now!

Comment: All though when I debug now, it gives an error in: "var results = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new BookModel" saying its a System.FormatException! Indatastring has the wrong format...

Comment: @Cleon hmm, this seems to be grammatical or format... check your C# syntax. Seems like you miss parentheses: `new BookModel() { .../*properties here*/ }`

Comment: I tried: "var results = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new BookModel()
            {
                Id = (int)x.Attribute("id"),
                Author = (string)x.Element("author"),
                Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
                Genre = (string)x.Element("genre"),
                Price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
                PublishDate = (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"),
                Description = (string)x.Element("description")
            }).ToList();"

Comment: Still get the same, am I missing something here?

Comment: @Cleon No `Id` in your `BookModel` as far as I can see. Checkout that my answer *omits* `Id`. You can initialize *less* properties, but not *more*

Comment: Great thanks. Now I get all the books shown in my website. Next step is for the user to input a search in the textbox for getting that data (book) they are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
using Andre_Kordasti___Programmeringsuppgift.Models;
```

before mentioning BookModel

```
@model IEnumerable<BookModel>
```

Edit:
Change your Action method to the following

```
const string FILENAME = @"c:\users\andre\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Andre Kordasti - Programmeringsuppgift\Andre Kordasti - Programmeringsuppgift\DataSource\books.xml";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

        return View(doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new BookModel
        {
            Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
            Author = (string)x.Element("author"),
            Genre = (string)x.Element("genre"),
            Price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
            Date = (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"),
            Description = (string)x.Element("description")
        }));
```

Comment: I get: "System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`6[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Decimal,System.DateTime,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Andre_Kordasti___Programmeringsuppgift.Models.BookModel]'." when debugging, do you know why?

Comment: All though when I debug now, it gives an error in: "var results = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new BookModel" saying its a System.FormatException! Indatastring has the wrong format...

Comment: then you have more problems in your code, The collection you are parsing should be strongly typed to match with view's model

Comment: I dont really understand, could you be more specific please?

Comment: May be your conversion is failing id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
            author = (string)x.Element("author"),
            genre = (string)x.Element("genre"),
            price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
            date = (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"),
            description = (string)x.Element("description")

Comment: Could you please check your data, which is being parsed

Comment: Oh yes, you should be creating exact properties in your select of BookModel

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned can be caused by the fact you are missing `using` statement in your view, or alternatively passing the model type with full namespace. But even if you add this, it would not work, as you do not pass the collection you are suppose to pass - in your controller you pass the `result`, which is a collection of anonymous objects, not `BookModel`:

```
var results = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new BookModel // <= missing
    {
        Author = x.Element("author").Value,
        Price = decimal.Parse(x.Element("price").Value)
        /* your properties*/
    }
```

Comment: Is that why I get: "System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`6[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Decimal,System.DateTime,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Andre_Kordasti___Programmeringsuppgift.Models.BookModel]'." when debugging?

Comment: Yes, exactly this is the reason. The model in `@model` statement in View should be the same type as the model you pass in you controller.

Comment: var results = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new BookModel
            {
                Id = (int)x.Attribute("id"),
                Author = (string)x.Element("author"),
                Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
                Genre = (string)x.Element("genre"),
                Price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
                PublishDate = (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"),
                Description = (string)x.Element("description")
            }).ToList();

Comment: This seem to be working now since its the same properties as in the model!

Comment: It should, you have to change properties from camel case to pascal case only, as you did in comment before

Comment: All though when I debug now, it gives an error in: "var results = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new BookModel" saying its a System.FormatException! Indatastring has the wrong format...

Comment: You should get `Value` from `XElement` and parse it to proper type, as it's a text (`string`), so casting would not work, see my edit

Comment: I dont really understand, could you be more specific please?

Comment: To get value from the element (`XElement`) you should use `Value` property. For your `string` properties you can assign them, but for other types you need to parse the value for proper type - I edited by answer to show the idea for 2 sample properties.